# Update Quantity of multiple products in one form Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, controller, many-to-many

I have an admin panel where I can view and edit orders. In Edit Order section, I have ordered products with pivot quantity. I need to update quantity of each product.

View:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
 <tr>
  <th>{{ $product->code }}</th>
  <th>{{ $product->name }}</th>
  <td> <input type="number" value="{{ $product->pivot->quantity }}" class="form-control" name="eproduct"></td>
 </tr>
@endforeach
```

Orders Controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
$products = array();
        foreach($data->products as $product)
        {
            $products[] = $product->id;
        }
        
        $ordered_products = EorderProduct::where('eorder_id', $id)->whereIn('product_id', $products)->update(array('quantity' => $request->eproduct));
        }
```

when I do `dd($request->eproduct)`, its showing only the last item quantity. And not updating anything.

Answer (score 0):

the input should be array

```
  <td> <input type="number" value="{{ $product->pivot->quantity }}" class="form-control" name="eproduct[]"></td>
```

Comment: I'm getting this error:
>Incorrect integer value: '["2","3"]' for column 'quantity' at row 1 (SQL: update `eorder_product` set `quantity` = ["2","3"], `eorder_product`.`updated_at` = 2022-05-11 12:43:30 where `eorder_id` = 317 and `product_id` in (348, 184))